# RxJs: forkJoin() doesn't run because my list of observables is incomplete

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, fork-join

Well I have a problem that I can not solve.

I am browsing a list of data from an XLSX file.
For each line of the file two requests are sent to the server:

- One to recover the **period**
- Another to recover a **user**

An observable **wallet** is created to store the rest of the data in the line. It is completed immediately after.
Otherwise, the loop would continue to execute and the last data in the list would be taken into account in the `forkjoin()`.

So I use `forkJoin()` to wait for the result of the three observables still in the loop.
Once the three observables have been completed, a new request is sent.
*And it's here that blocks him.*
The new query is added to a list of observables.

And I would like to run the rest of my code only after my list of observables is complete by using `forkJoin()` again,
after browsing the data from the XLSX file.
The problem is that my loop that runs through my file ends before my list of observables contains anything,
and the second `forkJoin()` never executes.

**CODE :**

```
for(var objectives of this.XLSXObjectives) {
    if(objectives.values != 0) {
        // 2 requests (period and user)
        var period$ = this.storePeriods.getPeriod(new Period({month: objectives.values[0].month, year: objectives.values[0].year}));
        var user$ = this.storeUsers.getUser(new User({num_seller: objectives.values[0].userCode}));

        // Observable (wallet)
        var XLSXWalletSubject: BehaviorSubject<Wallet> = new BehaviorSubject<Wallet>(null);
        var XLSXWallet$: Observable<any> = XLSXWalletSubject.asObservable();
        XLSXWalletSubject.next(new Wallet({
            wallet_name: objectives.values[0].walletName,
            user: null,
            period: null,
            margin_m: 0,
            value_100: objectives.values[0].ValueAt100Percent,
            percentage_100_m: 0
        }));

        // Wait for the result of the three observables
        forkJoin(period$, user$, XLSXWallet$).subscribe(
            ([period, user, wallet]) => {
                console.warn("OK!");

                wallet.period = period;
                wallet.user = user;

                // New request
                var wallet$ = this.storeObjectives.addXLSXWallet(wallet);
                // Request is added to a list of observables
                this.observables$.push(wallet$);

                wallet$.subscribe(w => { ... });
            }
        );
        // Observable (wallet) complete
        XLSXWalletSubject.complete();
    }
}

console.warn(this.observables$); // this.observables$ = []
forkJoin(this.observables$).subscribe(results => {
    console.log("It doesn't work!!!")
});
```

If anyone would have a solution to help me, thank you.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, everything in your loop completes before the second `forkJoin` is even called, hence why there's nothing in your `observables$` array. Are `period$` and `user$` synchronous?

Comment: Yes you are right the loop ends before. But I wish I could continue my code once all the data is recovered, but I do not know how.

Comment: I'm trying to put together an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain here, but I think what you need is something along these lines:

```js
from(this.XLSXObjectives).pipe(
  filter(objectives => objectives.values != 0),
  mergeMap(objectives => forkJoin(
    this.storePeriods.getPeriod(new Period({month: objectives.values[0].month, year: objectives.values[0].year}),
    this.storeUsers.getUser(new User({num_seller: objectives.values[0].userCode}),
    of(new Wallet({
      wallet_name: objectives.values[0].walletName,
      user: null,
      period: null,
      margin_m: 0,
      value_100: objectives.values[0].ValueAt100Percent,
      percentage_100_m: 0
    }))
  )),
  map(([period, user, wallet]) => ({ ...wallet, period, user})),
  mergeMap(wallet => this.storeObjectives.addXLSXWallet(wallet)),
  toArray()
).subscribe(results => { // handle array of results here });
```

- the objectives are emitted one by one
- the `mergeMap` subscribes to the `forkJoin` of your three inner Observables (if you need requests to be handled one at a time, use `concatMap`, and if you only want a certain number of simultaneous requests, add a concurrency argument to `mergeMap`)
- the `map` call populates your `wallet` object with `period: period` and `user: user`
- the final `mergeMap` makes the next request using the `wallet` object
- the `toArray` call waits until the whole Observable is complete and emits all received values as an array

Comment: I will look at it afterwards, I have errors of compilation because it misses some parentheses

Comment: Haha sorry, the problems of writing directly into SO ^^

Comment: It seems to be working, I'm going to do some tests this afternoon

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad :)

Comment: Hey, it's you wrote the course "Developing Web Applications with Angular" on OC. Thanks again ^^

Comment: Haha yeah that’s me ^^